# In what ways could "bitcoin" be hacked?

Tags: protocol, hacking

Dan Kaminsky said that he spent 4 months [trying to hack "bitcoin"](http://www.businessinsider.com/dan-kaminsky-highlights-flaws-bitcoin-2013-4?IR=T&) but failed.

Besides trying to find vulnerabilities in [double-spending](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/421/1475) and [51% attack](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1061/1475), what other hacks would a hacker try to achieve?

Surely an established hacker like Dan Kaminsky wouldn't have spent 4 months just trying to prove the protocol is immune to double-spending and robust against 51% attacks. There had got to be more things that he was trying.

Exactly what kind of hacks will a hacker try to achieve against bitcoin?

Comment: @Murch, Isn't this what I linked to in the question?... *"Besides the obvious problem of double-spending, exactly what kind of hacks were he trying to achieve?"*

Comment: I don't see where your question differs significantly from the linked, i.e. while the question is phrased a bit different, the answers to the linked question seem to cover your question as well. Could you please highlight/clarify which additional information you are seeking?

Comment: @Murch, Surely Dan Kaminsky did not spend 4 months only trying to prove the protocol is immune to double-spending and robust against 51% attacks. There got to be more things that he was trying. Exactly what kind of hacks were he trying to achieve?

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying. I have retracted my close vote but would like to suggest that you consider editing your question to reflect your intent more clearly.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Any established hacker would be able to answer this question.

Comment: Now that you've reworded, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

There could also be hacks targeting the bitcoin software implementation. If a vulerability is applicable to software running on majority (>50% hashrate) of the nodes then it is a real threat.

For example lets say someone can craft a mal-formed transaction that somehow can trick >50% nodes to accept it (for example induce a buffer overflow and somehow allow attacker to gain remote access to the node system itself and make modifications) then bad things will happen.

Comment: Hmm, so do you mean Dan Kaminsky (and various hackers) deemed the official bitcoin software implementation released to be flawless?

Comment: @Pacerier There's a distinction between not finding any issues and there being no issues to find.